# UNIX timestamp using for storing logs

Tags: postgresql, log, unix

Would it be feasible to use UNIX timestamp as a primary key to store log records/analytics data of users?
Will there be inconsistencies if a RDBMS is used to store log data?

Comment: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/